# Create multiple column array in Google bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery

Im trying to set the result of a query as an array. I can do this fine with only one column returned using the code below, but i get errors as soon as i try to add another column. How do i get multiple columns and store them in an array?

Thanks.

```
DECLARE my_array ARRAY<string>;

SET my_array = (
  SELECT ARRAY_AGG(value_1,value2)
  FROM `project.dataset.table`
  WHERE somthing = 'somthing'
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below

```
DECLARE my_array ARRAY<STRUCT<value_1 STRING,value2 STRING>>;

SET my_array = (
  SELECT ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(value_1,value2))
  FROM `project.dataset.table`
  WHERE somthing = 'somthing'
);
```

Comment: ahh thank you! I had tried STRUCT but was not declaring the array correctly.